# Laravel Forge won't deploy with git

Tags: php, git, laravel, ubuntu, forge

I'm using Laravel Forge to deploy a PHP site to a Ubuntu 16.04 x64 server. I deployed the site via git, and the site is up and running.

However, when I try to deploy new changes via git and Forge, I get the following error:

```
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader


  [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I get the same [PDOException] error on my local machine at the end of the following commands:

```
composer install --no-interaction

php artisan clear-compiled

php artisan optimize

php artisan migrate
```

Here is my Laravel .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=MYPASSWORD
```

Here is my config/database.php file:

```
   'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'MYPASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
```

When I try to connect to the remote database on Sequel Pro, I can SSH in, but then I get this error:

```
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:53986 forwarded to remote address 188.166.19.36:3306
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 53986.
debug1: channel 2: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 53986.
debug1: channel 3: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Connection to port 53985 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 53985 for 127.0.0.1 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 53988 to 127.0.0.1 port 53985, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 53986 forwarding to 188.166.19.36 port 3306 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 53986 for 188.166.19.36 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 53989 to 127.0.0.1 port 53986, nchannels 5
```

There is something going on with git and the database and Forge, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciate, thanks.

Comment: i think you should change the DB_HOST variable (thats your localhost adress

Comment: thanks, see my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DB_HOST=188.166.19.36 // i think this is the host ip if not change it to the right address
```

dont forget to put your password too and port(if thats not the default)

and in your localmachine you should change that too

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing the DB_Host like you suggested, but still got the error. But I am noticing that my deployments are working, it's just that I'm getting this error. For now I can continue, it's just some laravel issue...

Comment: I think the issue may be that I don't have a database and forge thinks I do? any ideas on this? thanks.

Comment: does your app require a database?

Comment: I don't know if laravel 5 does. I don't think I'm using it, as it's just a simple site with pages. I think forge builds a database though. It sent me the credentials in any case.

Comment: if you have pages without needing a data base, you need to change the env variables from the forge panel i guess

Comment: I notice I get the same error when I run php artisan migrate. Do you know why that might be? Thanks.

Comment: remove that from the deployment script, because that requires a database (cz that command created the tables)